# Custom Iterable<T>.sumOf function not working across different modules

Tags: kotlin, multi-module, kotlin-extension

I have this data class with me defined in module A:

```
data class Amount(val value: Int)
```

And I have created the following extension function (also in module A):

```kotlin
inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.sumOf(selector: (T) -> Amount): Amount {
    var sum = 0
    for (element in this)
        sum += selector(element).value
    return Amount(sum)
}
```

An example usage looks like this:

```kotlin
val sum: Amount = (1..5).sumOf { Amount(it) }
```

When I use this `sumOf` function in module A, it works perfectly but when I try to use it in a different module B (which has a dependency on module A), the compiler is not able to find this overload of `sumOf` function.

If I rename `sumOf` to something different (like `sumBy` etc.) then it works in module B as well. Another thing I noticed is that even if I put that extension function in module B, the compiler isn't able to find this overload. The error it shows is:

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.sumOf((TypeVariable(T)) → Int)   where T = TypeVariable(T) for    inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.sumOf(selector: (T) → Int): Int defined in kotlin.collections

followed by similar other overloads available for Long, ULong, etc.
```

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you didn't import your function, so it was at all ignored. Note that Kotlin stdlib already have a function with almost the same signature (`Iterable<T>.sumOf()`), so IDE probably don't even suggest you importing your custom function, but just uses the "standard" one.

It worked from A probably because you called it from the same package (just my guess), so it didn't require importing.

To fix this problem you would need to import your function manually, but I suggest not using this name at all. It will always cause confusion and problems - both to the compiler and to people who read the code and don't expect that `sumOf()` does a different thing than usual. Just name it `sumOfAmounts()`.

Comment: Import isn't the problem in this case. I even tried putting the function and invoking it from the same file, still didn't work.

Comment: So you say you have exactly the same file that contains both the function and a call to it, and this file works in A module, but it doesn't in module B? Anyway, I confirmed that if created such function and accessing it from another package (same module) IntelliJ doesn't suggest importing the function. But after adding the import manually, it works. But I can't explain your observations with it not working even from the same file.

Comment: The `Amount` data class is in module A and I want to call `sumOf` from module B (which depends upon B). I tried putting the `sumOf` function once in module A and then in module B, in both cases it wasn't working. Also, this is actually an android project with the different modules being gradle modules. Not sure is this has anything to do with the issue.

Comment: Where did you put `sumOf()` in module B in relation to the code that attempted to call this function? I ask because if they were in two separate packages, then the problem described by me would be still in effect. But if you put the function definition and the call to it in the same file (as you said earlier) then I don't see a reason why it might not work.

Comment: I tried both ways (putting the method in different module than the caller and also putting both in same file). Neither worked. Ended up renaming it to `sumBy`. Not it works, no idea why.